# What is the story with Jinja2 template pre-compilation?

Tags: jinja2

https://github.com/pallets/jinja says:

> Templates are compiled to optimized Python code just-in-time and cached, or can be compiled ahead-of-time.

Sounds great, I would like to deploy my site to AWS Lambda, with the templates pre-compiled (or cache pre-warmed, I don't mind which) to go fast from first request, without extra overhead on first use.

I could not find any explanation of how to do this in the docs though.

I found this: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.compile_templates

> Each template returned will be compiled to the target folder or zipfile.

But it doesn't say how to use the pre-compiled templates. Does it happen automatically?

I found this old issue: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/145 with reply from 2012

> You can use compile_templates() method and ModuleLoader: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment.compile_templates
>
> However, looks like bytecode cache is still faster.

So that points me to https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.ModuleLoader which explains:

> This loader loads templates from precompiled templates.

So maybe I know how to do that now, but I am haunted by the *"looks like bytecode cache is still faster"* part.

However, contradicting that, I found [this even older thread](https://groups.google.com/g/pocoo-libs/c/dIsNICT4j2Q) from 2009 claiming the pre-compiled templates with ModuleLoader are 3-5x faster than bytecode cache.

I don't see any guidance how to use that effectively. Presumably you then need a build step and maybe file-watcher etc to recompile the templates after you make any changes. I guess it'd make sense to only use the `ModuleLoader` in production and something else for dev.

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#bytecode-cache says:

> Bytecode caches make it possible to store the generated bytecode on the file system or a different location to avoid parsing the templates on first use.
>
> This is especially useful if you have a web application that is initialized on the first request and Jinja compiles many templates at once which slows down the application.

Sounds great, but it raises more questions than it answers - if the point of cached bytecode is to avoid compiling templates on first request, how does the cache get generated ahead of time?  Is there a convenience method, or I should script something to load all my templates in a build step?

Ok, the actual concrete questions:

- which is faster at rendering, bytecode or pre-compiled modules? (assume I am also precompiling all my project .py to .pyc via Python `compileall` tool)
- is there an easy way to pre-generate the bytecode cache?

Comment: After reading all of the places where BytecodeCache and its subclasses are referenced in the code, I don't think there's any built-in tool to automatically add all templates to bytecode cache. Seems like the only way to pre-generate it is to load every template.